# A Label, File Upload and a Button effect Domino Designer screen freeze?

Tags: xpages

I have a new Custon Control, in there I put a Label, a File Upload and a Button for user to upload file. Please find the code below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
 <xp:label value="File to upload" id="lbl_Desc"
    style="margin-left:100.0px">
    </xp:label>
    &#160;
    <xp:fileUpload id="fileUpload_control" value="#{document1.FileUpload}"></xp:fileUpload>
    &#160;&#160;&#160;
    <xp:button value="Upload" id="btn_upload">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
        refreshMode="complete" immediate="false" save="true"></xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
</xp:view>
```

I have form with a Rich Text Field and a view to store the data.

I create a new Xpage and drag that custom control to it. I open the xpage in Internet Explorer and try to upload a file for testing.

The contol work fine because I can see the upload file in the view and  able to open it.

Here comes the strange problem (I think), when I return to the Domino Designer, I try to click the custom control for further design, the Domino Desginer screen freeze. Why I would say that because I change to click to open xpage, the designer does not show it. The desginer just stay the custom control screen.

I close the designer reopen the xpage and the custom control, the desginer screen freeze again.

I don't know why the designer screen freezes, I redo the custom control again and the problem is not solve.
Would someone let me know where is my mistake please? Thank you very much.

Comment: Sounds like a buggy installation. Try a complete uninstall and reinstall of Domino Designer

Comment: Please confirm which release of Domino Designer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the amount of memory you're allocating to DDE. This is handled in /framework/rcp/deploy/jvm.properties. The relevant settings are "vmarg.Xmx" and "vmarg.Xms", the former being the maximum amount of memory allocated to DDE, the latter being the starting limit. There is a third, "vmarg.Xmca" I think, which handles the amount of memory added each time the threshold is reached.

Also, ensure you're using an up-to-date version of Domino Designer. In Xsp Properties, you can specify a version of XPages to compile against, e.g. 8.5.3. That can be used to ensure the application does not use later code. (Just remember to change that when the server is upgraded!)